# Why doesn't wget -m save the index.html documents

Tags: website, wget, mirroring

I'm making a copy of a website with

```
wget -m -p -q http://example.com
```

The process works fine, but the copy is missing all index.html files, even so I see them being sucessfully requested and all linked files are saved.

The only index.html that is saved is the homepage, but all subdirectories are missing.

Is there an important option I'm missing ?

Comment: Are the subdirectories of the form index.html/something? I've observed that wget glitches when a file and a directory have the same name (eg, "index.html" then "index.html/foo".) It also has a tendency to name files index.html if the URL ends in / or appears to be a directory (eg, "http://foo.com/bar").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
wget -m -p -d -v http://example.com
```

You are specifying the -q which deprives you of information that could help you solve your problem.  The -d and/or -v gives you more info.

I also notice that you omit the -r parameter.

If you wish to retrieve the index.html file from subsequent folders, then you should specify recursive.

Also, wget can only retrieve files and assets that are linked to the pages.  Any unlinked files and folders will not be retrieved.

From the manpage:

> wget -p http:///1.html
>
> Note that Wget will behave as if -r had been specified, but only that
>   single page and its requisites will be downloaded

Comment: I think -m should imply -r. The manual says -m is equivalent to  ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’.

Comment: I tried to specify -m and -r, but it made no difference.

Comment: And when you specify -d ... ???

Comment: -d produced an enourmous amount of output, but that finally led me to a 404 returned by the webserver for the index.html (access.log showed 200 !?). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to permission issue. To check this please execute the below command and check

sudo wget -m -p -q http://example.com

Comment: I ran wget as root, but it made no difference.